# A question regarding the proof of Laplace's expansion on Wikipedia

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am reading [the proof of Laplace's expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion#Proof) on Wikipedia and have a dilemma regarding the following:

> $\tau = (n, n-1, \ldots, i) \;\sigma^\prime\; (j, j+1, \ldots, n)$

As far as I know, such "products of permutations" are applied right-to-left (similar to composition), but this does not seem to be the case here (as it is written).

Namely, we know that $\tau(i) = j$ and $\sigma^\prime (n) := n$.

Attempting to compute $\tau(i)$ using the aforestated definition of $\tau$ and going right-to-left leads nowhere, however, going left-to-right gives us $i \mapsto n$ (first cycle), $n \mapsto \sigma^\prime (n) = n$ (middle), $n \mapsto j$ (last cycle), which is the correct answer. The left-to-right application also seems more consistent with my understanding of the proof.

Is there something I'm missing here?